# Need a form wizard technology that is configurable without programming

Tags: asp.net, infopath, wizard

I need a forms technology similar to MS InfoPath or Adobe LiveCycle Forms ES in that it has an XML data structure, is compatible with ASP.NET, renders in a browser, and is easily configurable by non technical office worker types. TurboTax Online is a good example of the type of functionality I have in mind.

The missing piece that I have not yet a solution for is that it be able to operate like a wizard such that responses to certain steps dynamically with AJAX or Flash/Silverlight or some kind of RIA either prompt or hide or alter subsequent parts of the form. It needs to be able to save all results or partial results to persistent form.

This would be easy to program the functionality but need a technology that can create / generate these forms and be able to set the rules in some sort of easily configurable way - the same way an office worker can create a form with InfoPath at least with perhaps a workflow style tool to set the ruls and flow of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Was there a reason you didn't investigate Adobe LiveCycle ES2 any further?

It seems to be a good fit for your requirements, and *does* have a wizard like feature called [Form Guides](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/workbenchHelp/help.htm?content=partGuides_1.html). You can hide/show sections based on user input, and have form events trigger calls to web services.

Given when you posted this, Guides may not have yet been implemented in LiveCycle - might be worth looking at again if this is still relevant for you.